# How to update snapshot with Jest and vue-cli

Tags: javascript, vue.js, jestjs, snapshot, vue-cli

I should be able to add `-u` parameter when running my tests, but I can't figure out why it doesn't work:

```
npm run test ComponentName.spec.js -u
npm run test ComponentName.spec.js --updateSnapshot
```

but it doesn't work. My package.json:

```
"scripts": {
    "test": "vue-cli-service test:unit",
```

I know I can just delete the snapshot files, but I'd like to figure out why the command doesn't work.

Answer (score 156, accepted):

Based on [the docs](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/cli#using-with-npm-scripts):

```
npm run test -- -u
```

I verified this works.

Comment: @SamuelFaure I found you can just have it like this in your package.json - "test:unit:update": "vue-cli-service test:unit -u"

Comment: Don't think you even need to add `run` anymore

Answer (score 16):

In vue-cli 3, your usual npm command calls vue-cli-service and not jest anymore. Vue-cli-service will call jest for you.

Either you can run :

`npm run test:unit -- -u`

the `--` is so that the next arguments have to be passed to the subcommand.

Or

`npx vue-cli-service test:unit -u`

This will run the tests and upgrade the snapshots.

Comment: `npm run test:unit -- -u` worked for me using `"@vue/cli-service": "^3.5.0"`, thank you!

Answer (score 10):

`yarn test -u` worked for me. We use yarn.

Answer (score 5):

If you are running a project with **Lerna** monorepo,

You probably want to add a new script to your package's `package.json` file:

```json
{
// ...
"scripts": {
  // ...
  "test:update:snapshot": "jest --updateSnapshot"
  // ...
}
// ...
}
```

So you can run

```sh
npx lerna run test:update:snapshot
```

Or you can just enter the package and run

```
npm run test -- -u
```

Basically `--` tells your command the argument `-u` is for its child command.

Answer (score 4):

npm run test -- -u [file_path]
//for particular file (thumps up to echo's answer)

Comment: Just to add it's enough to provide file name instead of path e.g `path/ComponentName.spec.js --u` you could write `npm run test ComponentName --u`

Comment: This also works with React Testing Library